# Highcharts - Enable styledMode but still allow custom styling set from outside

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to set styledMode = true in highcharts and allow custom styling set afterwards (via js) to be taked into account?

In my scenario I want all the default styling that highcharts sets via javascript to be disabled but I still want to apply my own via javascript along with other css stylesheets and was wondering if this was possible.

Why I'm asking this: if I enable styledMode = true and later on I do `$(myElement).highcharts(<custom style in json format>)` they seem to get ignored.

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible, but as the alternative solution you can use custom class as in the attached example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8y3zrcu2/. Related topic at our Highcharts forum:  https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44072